# C++ - "Could not load file or assembly 'EnvDTE100..."

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I tried to start a new project in Visual Studio 11 and I get a dialog box with this message:

> "Could not load file or assembly 'EnvDTE100, Version=10.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken = b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of it's
>   dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly
>   manifest."

I also tried to open an existing project/solution but I get this message from the output box of VS:

> "C:\Users\DANIEL\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\pointers\pointers\pointers.vcxproj : error  : No exports
>   were found that match the constraint: 
>     ContractName    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Project.IProjectServiceAccessor
>     RequiredTypeIdentity    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Project.IProjectServiceAccessor"

I'm new to VS and programming in general and I'm completely lost, yesterday I worked on a homework and it worked perfectly, now it just won't. Please help.

Comment: are you using an express edition of VS when this happens and a non-express edition when it works fine? also what version of windows are you using? Sometimes this is related to a .net installation and requires .net packages to be re-installed, need some more details about the setup where the error occurs and the one where it works fine if you can:)

Comment: If this worked before then this can only be caused by disk corruption.  Very unhealthy of course.

Comment: @GMasucci no, I've always used the 2012 ultimate version in my computer. it's a windows 7 64-bit btw. i'll try re-installing .net packages :)

Comment: @HansPassant come to think of it, I just had BSoD. I think I need to replace my boot drive. anyway i'll try re-installing both VS and .net, thanks for the replies.